# Why is my Delphi code not executing in order?

Tags: image, delphi, video, sleep

I am creating a program, and I need to display an image and then block input for a few seconds before allowing it again. The problem I am running into is that Delphi is not running the code in order and is executing the `Sleep()` command before the image command. I have run into this problem before when using `Sleep()` with a video before displaying a message.

The code looks as follows:

```pascal
procedure TtForm.WindowsMediaPlayer2Click(ASender: TObject;
  nButton, nShiftState: SmallInt; fX, fY: Integer);                          
Var                                                                            
  buttonSelected: Integer;                                                  
begin                                                                     
  buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Well done Monkey!-_-', mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);                                                            
  if buttonSelected = mrOK then                                              
  begin            
    Pages.Visible := False;                                                
    WindowsMediaPlayer2.Visible := False;                                      
    imgEroor.BringToFront;                                                  
    BorderStyle := bsNone;                                                   
    WindowState := wsMaximized;                                             
    imgEroor.Top := 0;                                                       
    imgEroor.Left := 0;                                                         
                                                                              
    imgEroor.Width := Screen.Width;                                                 
    imgEroor.Height := Screen.Height;                                       
    imgEroor.BringToFront;                                               
                                                                        
    BlockInput(True);                                             
    Sleep(10000);                                                         
    BlockInput(False);                                                    
  end;
                                                                   
  if buttonSelected = mrCancel then                                                    
  begin                                           
    Pages.Visible := False;                                               
    WindowsMediaPlayer2.Visible := False;                                   
    imgEroor.BringToFront;                                                 
    BorderStyle := bsNone;                                                      
    WindowState := wsMaximized;                                                
    imgEroor.Top := 0;                                                     
    imgEroor.Left := 0;                                                        
                                                                              
    imgEroor.Width := Screen.Width;                                         
    imgEroor.Height := Screen.Height;                                          
    imgEroor.BringToFront;                                                     
                                                                            
    BlockInput(True);                                                   
    Sleep(10000);                                                         
    BlockInput(False);                                                    
  end;                                                                    
end;
```

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong approach. You cannot sleep the main GUI thread and you should never use `BlockInput` (unless you are doing something very strange and advanced, and this is by far not a strange or advanced application). You really must redo this design from scratch. Buy a good book about Delphi programming and read it carefully. It doesn't matter if it is 10 or 20 years old -- the basics are the same.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I am still in grade 12 and this is for an easter egg in my IT PAT (Practical assesment task), so the knowledge I have is much less than anyone who has done Delphi for quite some time. This is the only way I know how to do this and our school issued books show no other way than using sleep.

Comment: Also, the code is definitely executing one statement at a time in the correct order. But you must understand that a Win32 GUI application is based on a message loop, so things don't happen until the right message has been processed. And you block the message loop!

Comment: If your schoolbooks suggest you use `Sleep` in a GUI app's event handlers, these books should be banned. Or possibly burned.

Comment: Talk to your instructor. The fact that you don't yet understand how GUI programs work, with the message queue etc., doesn't mean that you are excused from learning this. That's ultimately a problem you need to address.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not excusing myself from learning, this website is ultimately a platform for learning. I am asking for help and an explanation to this problem in order to gain a better understanding. also we are currently on holiday and I would not want to bother my instructor.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, what can I then do to , for lack of a better word, not block the message loop?

Comment: Never use `Sleep` in your GUI event handlers. Never use `BlockInput`. If you want something to happen in 5 seconds, say, use a `TTimer`. That one will make Windows generate a `WM_TIMER` message which will be picked up by the message loop.

Comment: Your MessageDlg has only 2 buttons. What is the point of writing 2 separate `if` blocks that do the *exact* same thing regardless of which button is actually clicked? [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I did try adding it after the if statements but it also didn't work so I tried putting it in each as a last resort. I was planing to do something with the cancel but I couldn't leave it blank so copy and pasted the code just as a filler for now. *Ps. Thank you for always editing my questions and sorry that I cause you so much work lol

Comment: Read Charles Petzold's book Programming Windows

Comment: Can you please name the book or link to the website you're using to learn from? I'm interested to what extent its lessons have questionable approaches.

Comment: @AmigoJack , it's called IT is gr8 @ Gr11 and IT is gr8 @ Gr12.

Comment: @David Heffernan , thank you. I will definitely look into it

Comment: @ParSec looking over the Table of Contents of that book, it appears to be a very high-level overview of "everything IT". I don't know what level of programming is involved, but you seem to be using Delphi, which runs on Windows to build Windows apps. That's fine. But Windows has a particular approach that's needed and it's reflected in Delphi. The use of Sleep and Blocking things may work in the other types of programs you're making, but they don't work in Windows and Delphi the same way. You need a different approach. Pay attention to what the folks above have said.